# Is there any way to shut down phone without root permissions?

Tags: android

Is there any way to shut down phone without root permissions ? I know that is possibility to restart,  but is there to turn off in any method (e.g. showing message to shut down) ?

Comment: Nope there is not. You need a DEVICE_POWER permission which requires rooted device. Best you can do is either set it to sleep or restart, but you already know that.

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic I though doing a reboot also required root permissions too?

Comment: @m0skit0 no, it isn't a duplicate. My question is "is there any way" and question given by you is about switching off on rooted device

Comment: yes my bad, you nee dpermission for that too

Comment: @Ty221 second answer in the **duplicated** question: *"You cannot do this from an ordinary SDK application. Only applications signed with the system firmware signing key can do this."* which effectively answers your question. Next time please read the whole answers. I took my time to read it and I'm not the one wanting an answer-

Comment: @m0skit0 Why -1 ? I cannot read every questions to find answer for my question. I checked suggested questions and I didn't find an answer (I read it carefully).

Comment: I removed the downvote anyway. This is first answer I found in my first search.

Comment: Stack Overflow has strange search system... Somebody is seeing something different than other body...